# How to get a custom user provider in an authentication guard?

Tags: symfony

I am using Symfony 4.0.5 and made a custom user provider for a special authentication guard like this:

```
class MyAuthProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
  ...
}
```

Then I want to use it in my authentication guard, but I do not know how to get my provider instead of the default database provider.

```
class SomeAuthentication extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        // $userProvider should be MyAuthProvider
    }
}
```

I previously registered it via security.yml:

```
security:
    providers:
        my_provider:
            id: App\Security\MyAuthProvider
```

At the moment my only solution is to dependency inject my own provider in the constructor of "SomeAuthentication" and don't use the given $userProvider from getUser(), but this doesn't feels right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple misconfiguration, you probably didn't set the provider of your firewall:

Example `security.yml`

```
security:
  ...

  main:
    pattern:   ^/
    provider:  App\Security\MyAuthProvider
    ...
    guard:
      authenticators:
        - your_guard
```

In the guard the `UserProviderInterface` parameter will be an instance of your `App\Security\MyAuthProvider` class.

You can parametrize that to be a little more flexible if you will:

```
parameters:
  security.provider.class: App\Security\MyAuthProvider

security:
  main:
    pattern:   ^/
    provider:  '%security.provider.class%'
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael. That was the mistake. I had assigned the Authentication Guard to the default/database firewall instead of creating a new firewall. Only one guard can run per firewall, if I understood correctly.

Comment: That's the magic! You can have as many as you want! Each will get executed until one logs the user in. For instance, one could try to authenticate you through Facebook, second one through Twitter, and so on, depending on the request.

Comment: How would you register multiple providers for the same firewall? For example if I have a firewall which you can access via database or token. Do I need one authentication guard handling both or can I have multiple authentication guards for each registration method?

Comment: You can inject the provider/repository in the guard's constructor.

Comment: Ok so I can use only one Authentication Guard for both methods, correct?

Comment: I don't understand your question. For single firewall you can have many guards but one provider. But that does mean you can't use [chained user provider](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/multiple_user_providers.html)

Comment: I wanted to use the default authentication for login forms (based on the database) and add an additional token-based authentication for the same firewall.
The solution was setting the provider key in the guard-section:
`security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            provider: database
            guard:
                provider: my_other_provider
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\MyAuthentication`

Comment: This is out of this question's scope.